# What is "t" in bicubic interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, bicubic

I was reading about bicublic interpolation on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation#Bicubic_convolution_algorithm). I came across the variable `t` which is not defined.

The equation is:

[image]

Can anyone please tell what this variable means and what are the usual value(s) for it?

Comment: I think this is supposed to be asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

t is any number between 0 and 1.

p(0) is the starting point of the curve and p(1) is end for one dimension.

for example by choosing sufficiently small dt you can plot a smooth curve like this

```
dt = 0.01;
for(var t = 0; t < 1 ; t += dt)
{
   draw( p(t) );
}
```